# find and findAll not working in grails 2.1.1/groovy 1.8.8

Tags: grails, groovy

I have some routines that are working in grails 2.1.0/groovy 1.8.6 but stop work in grails 2.1.1/groovy 1.8.8.

This code run in grails 2.1.0:

```
def items = []
Object[] item = ["Fluff", new Date(), 11235813]
items << item
println items
assert !items.findAll{it[0] == "Pelusa"}
assert items.findAll{it[0] == "Fluff"}
```

When I run it in grails 2.1.1, it throw this exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: 
Script1$_run_closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: 
(java.lang.String, java.util.Date, java.lang.Integer) values: 
[Fluff, Wed Sep 26 01:02:23 ??? 2012, 11235813]
Possible solutions: doCall(), call(), doCall(java.lang.Object), findAll()
```

That is some environment information:

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.2) (7u7-2.3.2a-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
```

How can I get it working again?

Edit: I think that it can be a Grails issue, because it runs fine on Groovy Console 2.0.1

Edit: It can be a bug. [I raised a jira issue.](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9443)

Comment: post the relevant parts of your code. Without it, we don't know what 'items' is.

Comment: Tried that code in Groovy 1.8.6 and 1.8.8 and it works in both...

Comment: I see what you mean...  It goes through [this line](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/GROOVY_1_8_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L2957) in DefaultGroovyMethods and that in turn fires the call method in [BooleanClosureWrapper](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/GROOVY_1_8_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/BooleanClosureWrapper.java).  It must be something to do with Groovy unwrapping the list as `items.findAll { a, b, c -> a == 'Fluff' }` works. No idea why it works in Groovy, but not Grails :-(

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates, I'm changing my code to use explicit variables in closure. It can be a bug and this is the workaround.

Comment: @AA. It also works as-is if you change `item` from an `Object[]` to a `List`

Comment: Yes but I don't build the `items` array, I get it from hql query and `executeQuery` function. Maybe I could coerce it to a List?

Comment: fyi: that issue had its deeper cause by a bug in Groovy that should be fixed with 2.0.5 (and 1.8.9): http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5730

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like

```
    assert !items.flatten().findAll{it[0] == "Pelusa"}
    assert items.flatten().findAll{it[0] == "Fluff"}
```

"items" is a list of lists so, "it[0]" will actually be the entire "item" list and not "Fluff". I dunno why this works in older versions of grails but not 2.1.0